# Text alignment in Textbox & Cursor height

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a series of input boxes that have some values in them. I fixed the vertical alignment problem with IE by adding a css property `line-height` to be the same as the height of the input box.

**Problem:** Now the `line-height` property cause the text cursor to be the height of the `line-height` property, and is not vertically centered in Chrome, but looks fine in IE.

How can this be fixed?

**jsFiddle** *(withoutline-height)*: http://jsfiddle.net/vzRZU/2/

**jsFiddle** *(withline-height)*: http://jsfiddle.net/vzRZU/3/

Comment: seemed to be working on IE without the `line-height` property. I am using IE9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/vzRZU/5/